# how to run wordpress and zendframework from the same docroot

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a site running in `wordpress` in shared hosting `terria.net`
I have developed another project in `zend` framework and have deployed under a tools directory,
I would like to access it `www.abc.com/tools`.

I have copied the content of .`htaccess` mentioned by Lorenzo Albertons in `tools/.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

But the url is not properly redirected to the tools project rather it is treating it as a `wordpress` page.

Comment: does your host allow reWrite with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

If `www.abc.com` points to your ZF app's `public` directory, then anything you put in there should be accessible via the appropriate URL segment using Zend's default .htaccess settings (the re-writing only kicks in if there isn't a physical folder or file already present).

We run a Wordpress site in our ZF application by just adding a symlink to the `blog`folder into the `public` directory, and access it via `wwww.abc.com/blog`.

For the record, we're using the follow rewrite rules (which I believe are default if you're use Zend's project generator, or at least were in ZF 1.8):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: the .htaccess in /tools mentioned by the OP is pointing to the wordpress index.php. The default .htaccess, noted by Bryan, should work perfectly.